# AngulrJS - technical reasons to use plain leaflet.js or the angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

What seems to be the official leafet.js uses [this syntax](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/examples/0000-viewer.html#/basic/first-example)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>

    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
        mapLink = 
            '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

whereas the `angular-leaflet-directive` uses

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("demoapp", ['leaflet-directive']);
        app.controller("BasicFirstController", [ "$scope", function($scope) {
            // Nothing here!
        }]);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="BasicFirstController">
    <leaflet width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>
    <h1>First steps, basic example</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I realize that the angular-leaflet-directive probably extends the basic leaflet,js, but is there any compelling technical advantage to use one over the other?

I can get both to work, but I can't get either to work in a UI-Router` view, not even nested in another element (such as a table, for alignment).

I suspect that the directive probably offer more power and flexibility, so seek some canonical advice. Technical factors, especially simplicity, but with power, are important, of course, but so is support.

No opinion-based answers please.

Comment: As with any AngularJS directive, its the ease of embedding it in multiple places and any code changes require just the directive to be amended and not everywhere its been implemented. However, you'll need to bear in the mind the directive may not be maintained and therefore using the leaflet.js library directly ensures you'll always be able to use the latest version.

Comment: A good summary - trading convince for possible uncertainty. It's always the same, I guess - does a wrapper allow one to do \*everything\* that the underlying code does? if so, I tend to go with the convenience of the wrapper, but if it precludes any functionality, then go with the core.  I suppose that if the directive is stable, one could go with that, even if development stops. I am currently trying to see how far I can get without it, and how burdensome it is to do so.  in this case, the directive has 100 contributors, so ought to be ok. However, it has 3 or 4 times as many issues.